# How to fix messed up MySQL installations on El Capitan (two installed), server won't start

Tags: mysql, osx-elcapitan

I've been pulling my hair for the whole day now so ANY help in clearing up this mess will be much appreciated. Google-ing and StackOverflowing did not help; versions move forward, instructions don't work anymore and I don't completely understand what I am doing so I keep making more and more mess. I really need a step-by-step checklist if anyone is willing to help.

I work on a MacBook Pro 13, early 2015 with El Capitan 10.11.3, upgraded from Yosemite. As it seems I have two MySQL versions installed:

- `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.11-osx10.9-x86_64/`- installed via .dmg
- `/usr/local/cellar/mysql/5.7.9/` - installed via Homebrew

I've also exported PATH variable in my .zshrc file like so:

```
(some stuff)

# User configuration
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

(some other stuff)
```

For a while I have been working on some SQL tutorials and all the time I thought I was starting MySQL correctly with:

```
> mysql -u root -p
> [password?]
mysql version ... \h to get help or ...
mysql> _
```

This would start the client (Homebrew one, 5.7.9). Now I realise that this was just the **client** and not the **server** itself so lesson learned there. The server I was using must have been from the .dmg installation (`/usr/local/`) because there is a subfolder `/data/` which has my databases in there. However, I cannot start that server as of today and get to these databases via the client; there is no `mysql.server` script like there is in Homebrev version of MySQL.

If I start the Homebrew client and do a `SHOW DATABASES;` sql, I cannot see these databases. It must be that this client is talking to another MySQL server (Homebrew one).

How can I clear up this mess? It seems to me that I need to:

- check which version of the server is running (if any)
- STOP it if it's the wrong one (it obviously is)
- start the right server
- start the client, connect to the server
- continue my work

The problem is, I don't really know how to do this properly via the command line. I `grep` and `launchctl` and I understand the basics of these commands but I must be doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Did you think about developing on virtual machines? So you can keep your mac free from all this installation stuff?

Comment: Pebbo - not really. I really wish to learn this properly so I want to dive into the mac's file system and all the options and that is why I insist on doing things through the command line.

Comment: Even if you plan on doing this, you can manually configure your virtual machine. Let's say you install a ubuntu system in a virtual machine. You could then afterwards install an apache, a mysql server and so on. Advantage would be that your own working machine would stay clean from all this stuff. AND if you want another person to work with you on a project, he would be able to use a copy of your virtual machine and won't have to setup all the stuff on his own. And you two won't have issues regarding version conflicts and so on :) just an idea.